# Set a background image for every uitableviewcell in a uitableview

Tags: objective-c, image, uitableview, background, cell

Well, I have a uitableview with 4 cells with content, so there are 4 cells displayed and other 4 cells displayed without content to fit the screen. I want all the cells in my uitableview to have a background image (the same for all). When I change the background of the cell on cellForRowAtIndexPath method only the 4 cells with content get the background image and the other 4 without content are still white. Is there any way I can set the background to all the cells an not only to the cells with content?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to add the additional four cells as blank cells to your table view. This way, they still look exactly like one of your other cells. An alternative may be to make the cells larger which would make you need to use less "filler" cells.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

increase the number of rows in the section....
lets say u want 100 cells to get the background image... then the cellforRowAtIndex path will be called for 100 cells and hence will set the background..

Hope it works 
Let me Know